# Debugging Nativescript on Visual Studio Code

Tags: android, genymotion, nativescript

I am trying, and failing, to debug Nativescript demo application via Visual Studio Code using latest Nativescript plugin. Also, I use Genymotion emulator ..

This is my launch.json:

```
    {
        "name": "Launch on Android",
        "type": "nativescript",
        "platform": "android",
        "request": "launch",
        "appRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "diagnosticLogging": false,
        "emulator": false,
        "rebuild": true,
        "tnsArgs": [
            "--device 1"
        ]
    },
```

and this is what I get for result:

```
Cannot resolve the specified connected device by the provided index or identifier. To list currently connected devices and verify that the specified index or identifier exists, run 'tns device'.
```

Running tns device from terminal:

```
┌───┬─────────────┬──────────┬─────────────────────┬──────────┬───────────┐
│ # │ Device Name │ Platform │ Device Identifier   │ Type     │ Status    │
│ 1 │ vbox86p     │ Android  │ 192.168.56.101:5555 │ Emulator │ Connected │
└───┴─────────────┴──────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────┴───────────┘
```

So far I tried the following:

- Reinstalling VSC Nativescript plugin
- Building latest Nativescript plugin from git repo
- Launching via --geny 'Custom Phone'
- Killing ADB server

However, I can run or livesync application normally via terminal, but the same doesn't work in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Did you go into VS Code, select the DEBUG icon on the left and then select ATTACH TO ANDROID EMULATOR from the combo box. Or kill the watch and do a LAUNCH ANDROID EMULATOR. I think you might have more luck with ATTACH - in that case you don't have to specify the device #.

Comment: Try to use default AVD Android Emulator - https://github.com/NativeScript/docs/blob/master/tooling/android-virtual-devices.md instead of using `Genymotion`. You could also delete `.vscode` folder from your project to be sure that `launch.json` file is not broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution wast to use default AVD emulator as @Nikolay Tsonev mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

I get it working -

```
On macOS systems, verify that you have added the following paths to the
PATH environment variable.

For Genymotion earlier than 2.6:
/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/
/Applications/Genymotion Shell.app/Contents/MacOS/

For Genymotion 2.6:
/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player.app/Contents/MacOS
/Applications/Genymotion Shell.app/Contents/MacOS/

For example: Run the following command 
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Genymotion\ Shell.app/Contents/MacOS/:/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/
```

then click on launch on android before that ensure your genymotion device is up and running.

For more info check here - https://www.nativescript.org/nativescript-for-visual-studio-code

Comment: That YT video is less than a month from be 3 years old. Is there any more recent videos on getting Nativescript debugging working in VS Code? I'm struggling mightily :-(